# Class memory management / structure with ivars obj-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instance-variables

I am still new to objective C so I am just trying to figure out some basic memory management techniques.

Class Method:

```
- (NSString*) updateWindowName: (NSString*) windowName{

NSDictionary *error = nil;

NSAppleScript *appleScriptUpdateWindowName = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                                   [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@\
                                    "tell application \"System Events\" to get the title of every window of process \
                                    \"BlackBee\" whose name contains \"%@\"", windowName]
                                   ];

//Execute and get the result of the OSAScript
NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [appleScriptUpdateWindowName executeAndReturnError:&error];

//Convert to the result to a string
windowName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];

NSRange range = [windowName rangeOfString:@"x"];
NSString *removeFrontOfString = [windowName substringFromIndex:range.location];
NSRange range2 = [removeFrontOfString rangeOfString:@"\""];
NSString *removeEndOfString = [removeFrontOfString substringToIndex:range2.location];

return removeEndOfString;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    //Create instance of Window Class
    Window *windowClass = [[Window alloc]init];

    //Get title of all running windows
    NSArray *windowTitles = [windowClass getWindowNames];

    while (TRUE) {
        //Get the current window name
        [windowClass updateWindowName:windowTitles[0]];

        sleep(0.20);
    }      
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am getting a string, feeding that string to be processed for cleaning and returning the cleaned up string. The problem is that I am leaking memory while doing so, nothing is being released it looks like each call to the window class is staying in memory. How do I release all variables / anything used by the class?

Secondly I am creating filters and applescript within each method as each method within my class has similar filters. Am I better off declaring the variables in the header file , or is generating them within the method better?

I know this is extremely fundamental/basic and I have done some googling but I am struggling to find the correct way to do this.

*EDIT*

Seems extremely likely the culprit is NSAppleScript and NSAppleScriptEventDescriptor, ARC will not allow me to manually release NSAppleEventDescriptor, I have tried wrapping my while loop in an autoreleasepool and I have tried putting the class method inside an autoreleasepool , both having no effect.

Answer (score 0):

To triage this specific problem, try putting an additional `@autoreleasepool` block just inside your `while` statement:

```
while (TRUE) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //Get the current window name
        [windowClass updateWindowName:windowTitles[0]];

        sleep(0.20);
    }
}
```

You're not doing anything with the returned string, but just because it's not being used/retained by anything doesn't mean that it will truly be garbage-collected/released back to the system, since you're never breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: I didn't do anything with the string because I was originally just creating a new string that was equal to the result of the call. Then I was NSLogging the output , as it happens so frequently I removed it because I thought that constantly printing could also be part of the reason why the memory usage was rocketing up. 

I just tried with the autoreleasepool and it didn't make any difference. I appreciate the input , anything else I can try? Memory usage is increasing at about 12mb/s anytime I run that loop.

Comment: I would try profiling using the Leaks Instrument; at that leakage rate, I seriously doubt it has anything to do with the strings.  You might also check the docs for NSAppleScript and NSAppleEventDescriptor to see if they have any clues.

Comment: Yea I think your right, I have checked apples documentation and even an example found here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2084/_index.html but ARC won't allow me to release *result, is there any way to force arc to remove the objects from memory each time I loop ?

Comment: I have also just tried wrapping the updateWindowName method inside an auto release pool and still didn't help.